# Angular2 Observable - Function must return value

Tags: angular, observable

i wrote an angular2 service.
The service should
 - load data from another service
 - work with the data
 - should itself return an Observable with data for components

So i wrote this:

```
getTimers(): Observable<Array<Timer>> {
        this.apiService.getTimers().
            subscribe(
            data => {
                this.variables.setTimers(data.length);
                let timers: Array<Timer> = this.formatter.formatTimers(data);
                this.setOngoingTimers(timers);
                return Observable.of(timers);
            },
            error => { return Observable.throw(error); }); 
    }
```

This is the error i get:

```
A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.
```

Can someone point me in the right direction??

Comment: Do not annotate local declarations like `let` statements. Let the compiler infer the type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`getTimers(): Observable<Array<Timer>> {` declares a return type but doesn't return anything.

I assume what you want is

```
getTimers(): Observable<Array<Timer>> {
  return this.apiService.getTimers().
        map(
        data => {
            this.variables.setTimers(data.length);
            let timers: Array<Timer> = this.formatter.formatTimers(data);
            this.setOngoingTimers(timers);
            return Observable.of(timers);
        });,
        //error => { return Observable.throw(error); }); 
}
```

The line

```
return Observable.of(timers);
```

only returns from the function passed to `map()` (former `subscribe()`), but not from `getTimers()`